# When entities are detached from the persistence context (JPA)?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

**Everywhere is written** that entities are detached from the persistence context **when transcation end** (commit or rollback). 
But in many examples you can see this code:

```
Customer customer = new Customer("Entony", "Bal", "eesmmro@mail.com");
tx.begin();
em.persist(customer);
tx.commit();
assertTrue(em.contains(customer));
em.detach(customer);
assertFalse(em.contains(customer));
```

Why em.contains(customer) return **true** when **transcation completion**? And why need to use **em.detach(customer)** after transaction completion when entities should be automatically detach from the persistance context?

Comment: JPA docs reveal such things. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/persistence.html#lifecycle

Comment: @BillyFrost, thanks! Find here(http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/persistence.html) info about Transaction PersistenceContext (default for JavaEE usage) and Extended PersistenceContext (default for JavaSE usage). It's obvious that in my listed code fragment use Extended PersistenceContext, when entities are not detached until EntityManager will not be close(), or entity will not be explicitly detach().